# Automatically close Redmine Task with commit comment

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial, redmine

There is a feature (associated revisions) in Redmine to link commits with tasks with specific keywords typed in comment on commit:

> Default keywords are:
>
> ```
> * for referencing issues: refs, references, IssueID
> * for fixing issues: fixes, closes
> ```

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages

When I make commits (from Visual Studio 2010 + Mercurial) to the repository, all referencing keywords are working fine but “fixing issues” keywords (fixes, closes) don’t change the status to “done”.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Log in as an admin and go to *Settings -> Repositories -> Referencing and fixing issues in commit messages*:

[image: redmine settings]

Make sure that:

- you have a status defined in the dropdown *applied status*
- you're using the correct keywords in your commit messages

The following examples will close an issue for the above settings:

- `fixes #1234`
- `closes #1234`

To have the issue get closed, redmine will have to read the latest commit messages. Usually redmine does this when clicking on the *Repository* tab. You may also configure a rake task which does this regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to this is "not possible".

Redmine has distinct statuses of "resolved" and "closed". You can map a set of keywords to a single status, but you can't configure different keywords to different statuses. In other words, you can't configure "fixed" to mean status of fixed at the same time that "closed" means a status of closed. You can do either, but not both.

Comment: In the current redmine it is now possible to map different keywords to different statuses.