# Link SVN commits to issues

Tags: svn, redmine

I know I can use #number to to link the commit to an issue. But I'm looking for a way to change the issue status through the svn commit.

I'm looking for something similar to what Trac have http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TimeTracking . If your svn comment is "This task is almos done (refs 123)" then it add the message on the issue's log.

Does anybody knows if there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this is in redmine OOTB:

> I'm looking for a way to change the issue status through the svn commit.

You can update the issue status by using the proper *Referencing keywords* as defined in your settings. 
See the [redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages) or [the answer to this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282684/automaticly-close-redmine-task-with-commit-comment/7292711#7292711) (screenshot below)

> If your svn comment is "This task is almos done (refs 123)" then it add the message on the issue's log.

When using the proper *Referencing keywords* in your svn message (as above), the revision gets associated to the issue and is being displayed in a second column called *Associated revisions* to the right of the message *History* (see [this issue](http://www.redmine.org/issues/8611) as an example).

In case you use *Fixing keywords* , an entry is also added to the issue's log, the status is modified and the *% Done* field is updated.

---

[image: redmine referencing keywords]

Answer (score 4):

Referencing issues in commit messages
When fetched from the repositories, commit messages are scanned for referenced or fixed issue IDs.
These options lets you define keywords that can be used in commit message to reference or fix issues automatically, and the status to apply to fixed issues.

Default keywords are:

for referencing issues: refs, references, IssueID
for fixing issues: fixes, closes
There's no default status defined for fixed issue. You'll have to specify it if you want to enable auto closure of issues.
If you want to reference issues without using keywords, enter a single star: * in the Referencing keywords (Administration/Repository) setting. In this case, any issue ID found in the message will be linked to the changeset.

Example of a working commit message using default keywords:

`This commit refs #1, #2 and fixes #3`

This message would reference issues 1 and 2 and automatically fix issue 3.
After a keyword issue IDs can be separated with a space, a comma or &.

Answer (score 0):

- In case of TortoiseSVN you have to find, install, configure proper [plugin for your issue-tracking tool](http://tortoisesvn.net/issuetrackerplugins.html)
- For command-line SVN (I suppose), most things can be done with
  post-commit hooks