# connect git commit message to redmine issues

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Is it possible to make redmine intercept the commit messages and act, like on assembla, if I commit and write fix #12 than issue 12 status changes to fix.
Any plugin for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No plugin needed, it works the same way as it [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616280/63733) for [SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8309830/63733) or [mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292711/63733).

However, in order for redmine to pick up the new commit messages, you either have to open the repository page in redmine, or schedule a task to do so regularly.

Answer (score 2):

Redmine has this functionality by default. You can use *refs*, *references*, *IssueID* for references and *fixes*, *closes* for fixing issues. You can also add your own keywords to be parsed from redmine and do stuff to your issues.

You can find more info on [documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages)

Answer (score 2):

as @afarazit said, plus you probably want the issues to update live in Redmine without needing to manually enter in the *Repository* tab to force the refresh.
That can be done by using this server-side *post-receive* hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

_apikey=YOUR_API_KEY    
_projectid=YOUR_PROJECT_ID

curl -k "http://REDMINE_SERVER_URL/sys/fetch_changesets?key=$_apikey&i
d=$_projectid"&
```

Comment: This doesn’t work as intended and gives a signal 13 error, but simply adding `while read oldrev newrev refname do … done` around the `curl` command fixes it.