# SVN check-in to close redmine issue ticket

Tags: svn, redmine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automaticly close Redmine Task with commit comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282684/automaticly-close-redmine-task-with-commit-comment)

Does anyone know how to force a link between SVN and a Redmine issues.

Most of the things I’ve seen on the web are related to using bash scripts and pre-commit hook, but we have a windows installation, so was hoping for something that would work in windows with little change to the server (i.e. minimal installation of third party programs).

For the moment, we are adding the # in to the comment field, which allows redmine to pick it up, but the end goal would be to have Redmine close a ticket on checkin with the right comment like “Close #”.

Is there a plugin anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have configured your Redmine instance, but usually the keywords for closing a ticket are "fixed #132" which usually closes a ticket without any pre-commit hook. Have you updated the repository browsing? Because Redmine will read the log entries only on demand not automatically.